# Gulp-watch task resulting in endless loop

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch, gulp-imagemin

I'm using 'gulp-watch' to monitor file changes under folder `images/`, and using 'gulp-imagemin' together with 'gulp-cache' to compress and **overwrite** the **changed** image files.

The `watch` task runs correctly and `img-minify` task stuck in endless loop when I add a new image file.

I've tried to eliminate the use of 'gulp-cache', however `img-minify` task still resulted in endless loop.

Thanks.

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    watch = require('gulp-watch'),        
    imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin'),
    pngquant = require('imagemin-pngquant'),
    cache = require('gulp-cache');

gulp.task('clear', function() {
    return cache.clearAll();
});

gulp.task('img-minify', function() {
    var paths = {
        src: 'images/**/*',
        dest: 'images/'
    };
    return gulp.src(paths.src)
    .pipe(cache(imagemin({
        progressive: true,
        use: [pngquant()]
    })))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.dest));
});

var paths = { 'img': ['images/**/*.png', 'images/**/*.jpg'] };
gulp.task('watch', function() {
    watch(paths.img, function() {
        gulp.start('img-minify');
    });
});

gulp.task('default', ['watch']);
```

Comment: Try using a different dest directory for your images.

Comment: @Barryman9000 Thanks. That might solve the problem, but I'd like to just overwrite the src images. Maybe the `gulp-cache` package could break the endless loop by `gulp-watch`, but I didn't find a way to achieve that.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are watching a folder and triggering a task which will modify that same folder. By doing that, the watcher will always catch a file change and trigger the task again, and again and again.

I guess you have two options.

1. Keep different folders for `source` and `distribution`; watch `source` and run the task on `distribution`.
2. Add filters to the path, so you don't watch the files you will be modifying.